# Scala/Java ORMs that fit the given criteria

Tags: java, scala, orm

Which Scala ORMs fit and work best with the following requirements?

- Sufficiently typesafe.
- Does not suffer from the 22-fields limit.
- Works with MySQL 5.5.
- Works with Scala 2.9.1.
- Is production-ready.

If no Scala ORM fits the criteria, please suggest a Java alternatives that does. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/), is quite good.

Comment: I was told by `@RaymondTayBL that it suffers from the 22-fields limit.

Comment: I was not aware of this limitation. do you know if it include POSO objects?
In release log[1] that say about POSO of ~50 fields.

[1]: http://squeryl.org/release-notes.html

Comment: It appears I was misinformed. Thanks for your answer! +1.